# mouse and keyboard are not working ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse, 17.10

i have installed ubuntu 17.10 but mouse and keyboard are not working after signing in and i don't have a network connection to update the drivers 
i tried to search about this problem but all results need a network connection

Comment: Question: when the mouse and keyboard do not work, are you still able to click on the dock and the topbar and does gnome-shell respond when you do that?

Comment: no , everything is not working after signing in .

Comment: keyboard is working until i enter the password

Comment: topbar is running in try ubuntu mode , can you help me with this??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_lightback=vendor` in the grub configuration file, at the end of the line starting with Linux, beside `quiet splash`. You can find the explanation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110624/what-do-the-kernel-parameters-acpi-osi-linux-and-acpi-backlight-vendor-do).

Comment: how can i edit the grub configuration file ?

Comment: just type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` in a terminal

Comment: i can't access the terminal from Ubuntu desktop .

Comment: can i use recovery mode??

Comment: i tried this but now the system is not loading 